# Showing error while fetching stat - Monitoring data

Tags: monitoring, apigee

I was trying out the first tutorial in Apigee. When I went to step 5: Monitor your API's performance - I got several error "Error while fetching stat"... and related errors when I changed the environment from prod to test to see the traffic.
Kindly help.

My api in test is running fine.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ritwik

Update: The problem has fixed itself. I did nothing. So not sure what was going on.
Additional details: Here are the tutorial steps that I was following:

"Now that you've deployed your API and made requests, you can use the data charts to see metrics.
First, look at the performance of all your APIs. In the management UI, click APIs. If the API Platform page is not open, click here.
If not already selected, select test in the Environment drop-down list at the top of the page. 
Scroll down to the Performance section to the chart displaying metrics for all of your APIs"

This is no longer a road-block, but I would like to know whether it was a problem with how I was doing things or an Apigee issue.

Thanks again.

Comment: What command specifically did you send?  Was this in the UI or via API?

Answer (score 0):

"Error while fetching stat" is a general UI message that usually occurs when the Analytics system is unable to process a query in a timely fashion.  This can usually be remedied by increasing the timeUnit, or shrinking the date range.

Were you running a report? Or, on some particular page in the UI?